# C++ high precision time measurement in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm interested in measuring a specific point in time down to the nanosecond using C++ in Windows. Is this possible? If it isn't, is it possible to get the specific time in microseconds at least?. Any library should do, unless I suppose it's possible with managed code.
thanks

Comment: No way you can take accurate time in nanoseconds with a time-sharing OS, in userspace. Don't listen to those who give you a function returning nanosecond counts — the data are useless. Kernel modules can do it though, and if you have hardware timestamps then you're set. Question needs way more detail.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have a threaded application running on a multicore computer `QueryPerformanceCounter` can (and will) return different values depending on which core the code is executing on. See  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN article. (`rdtsc` has the same problem)

This is not just a theoretical problem; we ran into it with our application and had to conclude that the only reliable time source is `timeGetTime` which only has ms precision (which fortunately was sufficient in our case). We also tried fixating the thread affinity for our threads to guarantee that each thread always got a consistent value from `QueryPerformanceCounter`, this worked but it absolutely killed the performance in the application.

To sum things up there isn't a *reliable* timer on windows that can be used to time thing with micro second precision (at least not when running on a multicore computer).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the poorly-known pitfalls to QueryPerformanceCounter. High performance timers on Windows just don't reliably exist, which is a giant PITA for some systems. Compare and contrast to Unix-based systems, which do it with ease...

Comment: Is this still true in 2013? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says *In general, the performance counter results are consistent across all processors in multi-core and multi-processor systems, even when measured on different threads or processes.*

Comment: @MartinThompson I don't know actually, it's been more than four years since I wrote this answer, things might have changed during that time.

Comment: QPC is perfectly supported in multi-core computers nowadays. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx for more precisions on this. Basically, processor counters have been time-invariant for a long time now and, if they are not, windows will use another (probably less precise) source to measure time.

Answer (score 16):

Windows has a [high-performance counter API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx).

You need to get the ticks form `QueryPerformanceCounter` and divide by the frequency of the processor, provided by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

```
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
if (::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency) == FALSE)
    throw "foo";

LARGE_INTEGER start;
if (::QueryPerformanceCounter(&start) == FALSE)
    throw "foo";

// Calculation.


LARGE_INTEGER end;
if (::QueryPerformanceCounter(&end) == FALSE)
    throw "foo";

double interval = static_cast<double>(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;
```

This `interval` should be in seconds.

Comment: Be warned, though, that intel's SpeedStep technology may change the PerformanceFrequency without your code noticing...

Comment: @xtofl: truth be told, the values of `QPF` are probably not all that accurate anyway (there was a good description of the risks somewhere). But repeated measures tend to average this out relatively well.

Comment: QueryPerformanceFrequency/Coutner doesn't necessarily use the system clock for that very reason.  However that means it uses another, lower frequency timer.  Either the PIC timer, ACPI timer, or the HPET on very new systems.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/05/3695356.aspx for some details

Comment: For this very reason, recent versions of Windows won't use rdtsc for QPC, and hence don't return the processor frequency for QPF. They might use the 1.193182 MHz programmable interrupt timer (PIT) or the high-speed (>10 MHz) HPET.

Comment: QPF gives counts per second, so interval in this code is in seconds, not nanoseconds.

Comment: FWIW it seems Windows 7 uses the HPET  :)  Getting much better resolution, since I upgraded from Vista.

Comment: I have been using a wrapper class over QPC, which compensates for QPC sliding away on long runs in the same time giving sufficient precision with short time measurements, [`CUsAccurateFileTime::GetTime`](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Common/alax.info/roatlcom.h#L3315).

Answer (score 9):

For future reference, with Windows Vista, 2008 and higher, Windows requires the hardware support "HPET". This operates independently of the CPU and its clock and frequency. It is possible to obtain times with accuracies to the sub-microsecond.

In order to implement this, you DO need to use QPC/QPF. The problem is that QPF (frequency) is a NOMINAL value, so using the raw calls will cause time drifts that can exceed minutes per day. In order to accound for this, you have to measure the actual frequency and check for its drift over time as heat and other physical operating conditions will affect it.

An article that describes this can be found on MSDN (circa 2004!) at this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx

I did implement something similar to this myself (and just found the above link today!) but prefer not to use "microsecond time" because the QPC call itself is rather lengthy compared to other Windows calls such as GetSystemTimeAsFileTime, and synchronization adds more overhead. So I prefer to use millisecond timestamps (approx 70% less call time than using QPC) especially when I'm trying to get the time hundreds of thousands of times per second.

Answer (score 5):

The best choice are the functions `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.

Microsoft has just recently (2014) released more detailed information about QueryPerformanceCounter:

See [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN 2014) for the details.

This is a comprehensive article with lots of examples and detailed description. A must read for users of QPC.

Answer (score 5):

I think microseconds is a bit unreasonable (without hardware assistance).  Milliseconds is doable, but even then not that accurate due to various nefarious counter resolution issues.  Regardless, I include my own timer class (based on std::chrono) for your consideration:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <chrono>


class Stopwatch final
{
public:

    using elapsed_resolution = std::chrono::milliseconds;

    Stopwatch()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    void Reset()
    {
        reset_time = clock.now();
    }

    elapsed_resolution Elapsed()
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<elapsed_resolution>(clock.now() - reset_time);
    }

private:

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point reset_time;
};
```

Note that under the hood on Windows std::chrono::high_resolution_clock is using QueryPerformanceCounter, so it's just the same but portable.

Comment: You are one of the few who don't immediately jump out of the `<chrono>` type system with `.count()` and return a bare integral type.  +1 for that! :-)

Comment: Am I allowed to use your code in a commercial project?

Comment: You certainly are.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Scenario) claims that -

> A Scenario object is a highly-accurate timer that logs ETW events
>   (Event Tracing for Windows) when you start and stop it. It's designed
>   to be used for performance instrumentation and benchmarking, and comes
>   in both C# and C++ versions. ... As a rule of thumb on modern
>   hardware, a call to Begin() or End() takes on the order of a
>   microsecond, and the resulting timestamps are accurate to 100ns (i.e.
>   0.1 microseconds). ... Versions are available for both .NET 3.5 (written in C#), and native C++, and run on both x86 and x64
>   platforms. The Scenario class was originally developed using Visual
>   Studio 2008, but is now targeted at developers using Visual Studio
>   2010.]

From [Scenario Home Page](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Scenario). As far as i know, it was provided by the same people as PPL.

Addionaly you can read this [High Resolution Clocks and Timers for Performance Measurement in Windows](http://performancebydesign.blogspot.ru/2012/03/high-resolution-clocks-and-timers-for.html).

Answer (score 3):

In newer Windows versions [you probably want `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [Acquiring high resolution timestamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Lots of this varies a rather unfortunate amount based on hardware and OS version.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the Visual Studio compiler 2012 or higher, you can well use the [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) standard library.

```
#include <chrono>

::std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

Note that the [MSVC 2012 version may be only 1ms accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16299029/2079934). Newer versions should be accurate up to a microsecond.

Comment: For better portability you might want to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead (it may or may not be the same as `steady_clock` but at least semantically it is a better choice).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use the Performance Counter API as Konrad Rudolf proposed, but should be warned that it is based on the CPU frequency.  This frequency is not stable when e.g. a power save mode is enabled.  If you want to use this API, make sure the CPU is at a constant frequency.

Otherwise, you can create some kind of 'statistical' system, correlating the CPU ticks to the PC BIOS clock.  The latter is way less precise, but constant.

Answer (score 0):

using [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338) (for windows)

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Konrad Rudolph's answer, note that in my experience the frequency of the performance counter is around 3.7MHz, so sub-microsecond, but certainly not nanosecond precision.  The actual frequency is hardware (and power-save mode) dependent.  Nanosecond precision is somewhat unreasonable in any case since interrupt latencies and process/thread context switching times are far longer than that, and that is also the order of magnitude of individual machine instructions.

Comment: Not in my experience. See [rdtsc x86 instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_278.html). It reads a counter updated every CPU clock cycle.

Comment: @JonasByström: The Windows performance counter API doe not use the TSC for the reasons described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).  The TSC is much higher resolution but less consistent.  Also this answer is five years old, and its content may or may not still be valid.

Comment: @JonasByström: Also in [this discussion](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/queryperformancefrequency-return-value-488039.html), it can be seen that results on my PC were very different from those of the question in discussion. YMMV. It is entirely hardware implementation dependent.

Comment: You're right in that it is implementation-specific, but I've only ever seen it implemented using TSC or better. And 3.7MHz seems a very low number for anything newer than P5 (launched 21 years ago?).

Answer (score 0):

[`rdtsc` instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is  the most  accurate.

Comment: In English (although with different content) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: Sorry. I did not pay attention. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Timer class that will work both for Windows and Linux :

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_CTIMER_HPP_
#define INCLUDE_CTIMER_HPP_

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define NOMINMAX // workaround a bug in windows.h
#  include <windows.h>
#else
#  include <sys/time.h>
#endif

namespace Utils
{
   class CTimer
   {
   private:
#     if defined(_MSC_VER)
         LARGE_INTEGER m_depart;
#     else
         timeval m_depart;
#     endif

   public:
      inline void start()
      {
#        if defined(_MSC_VER)
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_depart);
#        else
            gettimeofday(&m_depart, 0);
#        endif
      };

      inline float GetSecondes() const
      {
#        if defined(_MSC_VER)
            LARGE_INTEGER now;
            LARGE_INTEGER freq;

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

            return (now.QuadPart - m_depart.QuadPart) / static_cast<float>(freq.QuadPart);
#        else
            timeval now;
            gettimeofday(&now, 0);

            return now.tv_sec - m_depart.tv_sec + (now.tv_usec - m_depart.tv_usec) / 1000000.0f;
#        endif
      };
   };
}
#endif // INCLUDE_CTIMER_HPP_
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input...though I couldn't get nano, or microsecond resolution which would have been nice, I was however able to come up with this...maybe someone else will find it usefull.

```
    class N_Script_Timer
{
    public:
        N_Script_Timer()
        {
            running = false;
            milliseconds = 0;
            seconds = 0;
            start_t = 0;
            end_t = 0;
        }
        void Start()
        {
            if(running)return;
            running = true;
            start_t = timeGetTime();
        }
        void End()
        {
            if(!running)return;
            running = false;
            end_t = timeGetTime();
            milliseconds = end_t - start_t;
            seconds = milliseconds / (float)1000;
        }
        float milliseconds;
        float seconds;

    private:
        unsigned long start_t;
        unsigned long end_t;
        bool running;
};
```

Comment: To improve your resolution, you may want to add `timeBeginPeriod(1)` and `timeEndPeriod(1)` in `Start()` and `End()`, respectively.