# Is Thrust synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm new to using Thrust and there is one thing I don't understand. Is Thrust asynchronous or synchronous?

If I write the following code, the time taken isn't `0`. But in the other tags, other users report a result of `0`. What is the truth?

```c++
clock_t start,end;

start=clock(); 
thrust::sort_by_key(vettore.begin(), vettore.end(), counter.begin()); 

end=clock();

double time=((double)(end-start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 

cout<<"execution time"<<time<<endl;// the result is 0.327
```

Comment: Note: related question on the NVIDIA forum [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/864759/is-thrust-copy-synchrous-or-asynchronus-/).

Answer (score 3):

Kernel launches have always been asynchronous - even in CUDA 1.0 - so any Thrust call that results only in a kernel launch will be asynchronous.

Any Thrust code that implicitly triggers memcpy's will be synchronous due to the lack of stream support, as alluded to by marina.k.

Comment: For example, thrust::reduce() is definitely synchronous since it reads back the result and returns it to the calling thread via the return value. I make some comments about these limitations in my recent blog post on Thrust: http://developer.nvidia.com/content/expressive-algorithmic-programming-thrust

Comment: Honest question, does this answer need an update? See the changelog for Thrust 1.16.0: “ Thrust 1.16.0 provides a new “nosync” hint for the CUDA backend, as well as numerous bugfixes and stability improvements.

NEW thrust::cuda::par_nosync EXECUTION POLICY
Most of Thrust’s parallel algorithms are fully synchronous and will block the calling CPU thread until all work is completed. This design avoids many pitfalls associated with asynchronous GPU programming, resulting in simpler and less-error prone usage for new CUDA developers. Unfortunately, this improvement in user experience …”

Answer (score 0):

clock() function's granularity is not good as you think in Windows. And in Windows XP its granularity is as high as 16msec.

Instead of using clock() use a high resolution timer or Cutil library's timing functions (which is generally preferred).

Discussion about High resolution timer in Windows: 
[C++ high precision time measurement in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825720/c-high-precision-time-measurement-in-windows)

Discussion about CUtil library's usage for timing: 
[CUDA: CUtil timer - confusion on elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704681/cuda-cutil-timer-confusion-on-elapsed-time)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it manually add the time.h to the indexer, go to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer and put it in front of the existing "Files to be indexed up-front" like this:

```
time.h, cstdarg, stdarg.h, .....
```

it going to work