# High resolution timer library in C++ Windows?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ high precision time measurement in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825720/c-high-precision-time-measurement-in-windows)

I am developing a program that downloads files from ftp, and am looking for a High-Res timer library to calculate download speed, for now I am using c++ time(NULL), but results aren't accurate.

Is there a simple/easy to use, plug N play kind of c++ library for windows platform ? Something that gives time elapsed in seconds since last call or something similar.

**EDIT:**

So the QueryPerformanceCounter() was mentioned many times, but going through other threads this is what I found out :

*You should be warned that it is based on the CPU frequency. This frequency is not stable when e.g. a power save mode is enabled. If you want to use this API, make sure the CPU is at a constant frequency.*

*Be warned, though, that intel's SpeedStep technology may change the PerformanceFrequency without your code noticing*

*We also tried fixating the thread affinity for our threads to guarantee that each thread always got a consistent value from QueryPerformanceCounter, this worked but it absolutely killed the performance in the application. *

So considering the situation is it advisable to use it ? The performance of the program and reliablity of the timer is very important

Comment: Presenting... C++11's... `std::chrono`!

Answer (score 3):

You have QueryPerformanceCounter provided you don't fall into the buggy use-case described in the remarks [on the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Example from: [How to use QueryPerformanceCounter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter)

```
#include <windows.h>

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}

int main()
{
    StartCounter();
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << GetCounter() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yup, looks like trouble. Any working example you can point me to or maybe a wrapper class ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a compiler that support C++11, then you can simply use `std::chrono`, if not then `boost::chrono` is at your service

Comment: He could also use some elaboration of the BENEFITS you get from using `std::chrono` (you know, gurantees...).

Comment: @BigBoss How do I know if my compiler support c++11 ? I don;t even know what c++11 is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `timeGetTime`, the resolution should be sufficient for your needs.