# Is clock() reliable for a timer?

Tags: c++, clock, ctime

I'm using  clock(), and I'm wondering whether it ever resets or maxes out. all I'm using it for is just too subject it from a previous function call and find the difference.

Thanks for the help so far but I'm not really able to get the chrono thing working in VS '12 but its fine because I think its a little more than I need anyway, I was think about using 's time() but I have no idea how to convert the t_time into an int that contains just the current seconds 0-60, any help?

Comment: If you're worried about it, check out librt's clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...) instead.  That might be more in line with what you want, assuming you are allowed to use the librt library.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the standard is concerned,

> The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and `time_t` are implementation-defined.

(C99, §7.23.1 ¶4)

so there are no guarantees of range; the definition of `clock()` does not say anything about wrapping around, although it says that

> If the processor time used is not available or its value cannot be represented, the function returns the value `(clock_t)(-1)`

So we may say that exceeding the range of `clock_t` may be seen as "its value cannot be represented"; on the other hand, this interpretation would mean that, after some time, `clock()` becomes completely useless.

In facts, if we get down to a specific implementation (glibc), we see:

```
matteo@teokubuntu:~$ man 3 clock
```

> ```
>    Note that  the  time  can  wrap  around.   On  a  32-bit  system  where
>    CLOCKS_PER_SEC  equals 1000000 this function will return the same value
>    approximately every 72 minutes.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what system you are on. It may use a 32+ or a 64-bit `clock_t`. It will definitely roll over, but if it's 64-bit, it will be OK for quite some time before it rolls over - 2<sup>64</sup> microseconds is still an awful long time (approx 2<sup>44</sup> seconds, and there is around 2<sup>16</sup> seconds per day, so 2<sup>28</sup> days - which is about 2<sup>20</sup>, or  a million, years... ;)

Of course, in a 32-bit system, we have about 2<sup>12</sup>=4096 seconds at microsecond resoltion. An hour being 3600s = about 1h10m.

However, another problem, in some systems, is that `clock()` returns CPU time used, so if you sleep, it won't count as time in `clock()`.

And of course, even though `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` may be 1000000, it doesn't mean that you get microsecond resultion - in many systems, it "jumps" 10000 units at a time.

In summary, "probably a bad idea".

If you have C++11 on the system, use `std::chrono`, which has several options for timekeeping that are sufficiently good for most purposes (but do study the [`std::chrono` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono))

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>  // replace with "windows.h" if needed.

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
// 10 seconds on a unix system. Sleep(10000) on windows will be the same thing
    sleep(10);   
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
                             (end-start).count();
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds << "s\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was having a lot of trouble with chrono though do you think you could give me a code where it just returns the amount of seconds since the last time it was called?

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));` is C++11 equivalent for `sleep` (may be not supported in some compilers)

Comment: @milleniumbug: Thanks. Couldn't be bothered to try to look it up - I don't use `chrono` very much, so I just used something I knew what it was. I guess I could have used `char dummy; cin >> dummy;` instead...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well, it certainly doesn't matter in this example - just thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that if you're just using it to time a function, it will probably not wrap around. It may also be too slow and chances are you might see a function duration of zero. If you want accurate timing for a function that executes fast, you're probably better using an OS level call like [this one on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825720/c-high-precision-time-measurement-in-windows).