# C microseconds in windows?

Tags: c, windows, time

Ok, I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451354/lua-microseconds-sleep) a couple hours ago and I decided to make the same test using C.

Example 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Time testing, pure c\n");

    struct timeval tv;
    int i;
    int values[1000];
    useconds_t usec = 1000;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
        values[i] = tv.tv_usec;
        usleep(usec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", values[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
110977
111977
112977
113977
114978
115978
116978
...
```

Ok, not bad! 1 ms sleep is ok, now let's try 100 us sleep (same code, only usec = 100):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Time testing, pure c\n");

    struct timeval tv;
    int i;
    int values[1000];
    useconds_t usec = 100;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
        values[i] = tv.tv_usec;
        usleep(usec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", values[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
674680
675680
676680
677680
678680
679680
680681
681681
...
```

That's bad, beacause it's the same result! Only milliseconds are changed and usecs are not changing!
So what's going on and where is my mistake?
And can I get microseconds in windows properly?

Comment: Suggestion: `void main()`--> `int main(void)`.

Comment: What happens if you set `usec` to `1`?

Comment: @alk same as usec = 100

Comment: Btw, I dont't think this question is dublicate, because c++ is not c, imho...

Comment: @J.Leeroy The accepted answer of the duplicate applies to C as well.