# Why is clock() returning 1.84467e+13?

Tags: c++, clock, timing

I am trying to time a code I've got in C++. I have an inner and an outer loop that I want to time separately, but at the same time. For some reason when I do this one of the instances returns 1.84467e+13 and always this exact number.

Why is this happening?

Here is a minimum working example that replicates the effect on my machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int i, j;
    clock_t start, finish, tick, tock;
    double a = 0.0;
    double adding_time, runtime;

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        a=0.0;
        tick =clock();
        for(j=0; j<10000000; j++)
        {
            a+=1;
        }
        tock= clock();
        adding_time = (double)(tick - tock)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Computation time:" << adding_time << endl;

    }
    finish = clock();
    runtime = (double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Total computation time:" << runtime << endl;
}
```

Comment: The output is not exactly the same!

Comment: if you want high precision, do not use `clock()`. [C++ Cross-Platform High-Resolution Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487695/995714), [C++ high precision time measurement in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1825720/995714), [High resolution timer with C++ and Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/538609/995714)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `clock_t` is apparently an unsigned 64-bit type.

You're taking `tick - tock`, where `tock` was measured *after* `tick`, so if there's any difference between the two at all, it's going to try to produce a negative number--but since it's an unsigned type, that's wrapping around to become something close to the largest number that can be represented in that type.

Obviously, you really want to use `tock-tick` instead.

Answer (score -2):

let say tic = 2ms and tac is 4ms;  so when you do tic-tac(2-4) that will generate a negative number obviously.. even if it given a positive number it wont be the real time. and also, the number it generate (which doesnt appear on my computer) is a big number, so, try to use the manipulator;

```
#include"iomanip" 
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
cout << setprecision(2);
```

it might work..